# Sorting Of fetch_assoc

Tags: php, html, mysql, web

First of all I would like to say that I am very new to programming and that I have only had a few classes of it.

I am currently developing a new site just for fun, that me and my colleagues at work can use, because right now everything from messages, check-lists to shift-plans is written in hand. I work at a normal mall.

The site is in very early state, and i have made a "wall" that users can post messages to, and then the messages will be available for all users. The way the wall "works" is that it fethces the messages from a mysql database. It works fine now, but the only problem I have is that the oldest message is displayed first instead of the newest one. So my *question* is - How can I sort the messages so that the newest message is shown on top of the page instead of the oldest.

Btw, i am from denmark, and the website is also danish, but that shouldn't stop you from seeing my problem ([screenshot..](http://i.gyazo.com/67cd5ffbb56d8bd3076413f6109bc648.png)).

Here is the php script that i use to display the messages.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['nyt_opslag']))
            {
            header("location:nyt_opslag.php");
            }

{
            $con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die ("Cannot connect");
            mysqli_select_db($con, "persintra") or die ("Cannot select DB");

            $opslag= "SELECT *
                    FROM users
                    INNER JOIN opslag 
                    ON users.enummer= opslag.author;";
            $resultopslag = $con->query($opslag);   
        if ($resultopslag->num_rows > 0) {
             // output data of each row
             while($row = $resultopslag->fetch_assoc()) {
                 echo "<hr>";
                 echo "Dato & Tid: " . $row['timestamp'] . "<br />" . "Navn: " . $row['navn'] .  "<br /> E-mail: " . $row['email'] . "<br /> Telefonnummer: " . $row['telefon'] . "<br /> Adresse: " . $row['adresse'] . "<br /> Besked:<br />" . $row['message'];
                 echo "<hr> <br />";
             }
        } else {
            ?> </h4> <span class="servermessage"> <?php
             echo "Ingen indlæg";
        }
            $con->close();
            }


?>
```

Comment: You can use an `ORDER BY` - Consult http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Comment: Add a timestamp column to your table and specify an `ORDER BY` clause in your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use order by in your query...

```
$opslag= "SELECT * FROM users INNER JOIN opslag ON users.enummer= opslag.author ORDER BY timestamp DESC";
```